# Android how to parse this custom xml fie?

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I have implemented XML Pull Parser for local XML file stored in xml folder. I need to implement the same for XML in some destinated URL, how to pass URL to XML Pull parser ?

i tried like this below code i am getting error.

```
parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(getUrlData(url)));
```

the xml file looking like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource-lists xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:resource-lists">
   <list name="friends">
     <entry uri="sip:bob@example.com">
        <display-name>subbu</display-name>
     </entry>
     <entry uri="sip:maa@example.com">
        <display-name>raja</display-name>
     </entry>
  </list>
</resource-lists>
```

how to read this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xmlpullparser have this method to get data from URL call this function like this

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();       
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(getUrlData("url as string")));
```

function for getting data from url.

```
public InputStream getUrlData(String url) throws URISyntaxException, 
                                          ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
    HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
    return res.getEntity().getContent();
}
```